# Bad loops with JSP

Tags: java, loops, jsp, foreach

Trying to traverse 2 arrays and compare if the entities are equal for setting the "selected" propierty

Wanted something like this:

[image]

And I got this:

[image]

In the code: 
items="${listadoPaises}" var="pais" is allCountries (allPaises)
items="${divisa.paises}" var="paisoption" is the countries I want to be checked

```
<select multiple id="paisesSeleccionados" name="paisesSeleccionados">
    <option value="" disabled>País</option>
        <c:forEach items="${listadoPaises}" var="pais">
            <c:forEach items="${divisa.paises}" var="paisoption">

                <c:choose>
                    <!-- If the id is equal, set the SELECTED property -->
                    <c:when test="${pais.idpais==paisoption.idpais}">

                        <option selected value="${pais.idpais}" data-icon="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/flags/${pais.siglas}.png">
                            ${pais.nombre}
                        </option>
                    </c:when>
                    <!-- Else, not setting the property -->
                    <c:otherwise>

                        <option value="${pais.idpais}" data-icon="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/flags/${pais.siglas}.png">
                            ${pais.nombre}
                        </option>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>

            </c:forEach>
        </c:forEach>
</select>
```

It has to be a little mistake, maybe it´s easy but i´m getting totally crazy.
Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I had to add a new a <% and <%= expression tag with the selected string to fix it. Here the code:

```
<select multiple id="paisesSeleccionados" name="paisesSeleccionados">
    <option value="" disabled>País</option>

    <c:forEach items="${listadoPaises}" var="pais">
        <% String selected=""; %>
        <c:forEach items="${divisa.paises}" var="paisoption">

            <c:if test="${pais.idpais==paisoption.idpais}">
                <% selected="selected"; %>
            </c:if>

        </c:forEach>  
        <option <%= selected %> value="${pais.idpais}" data-icon="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/flags/${pais.siglas}.png">${pais.nombre}</option>        
    </c:forEach>

</select>
```